# Celery task is recieved but not executed when using gevent or eventlet (works with prefork)

Tags: django, firebase, celery, celery-task

I'm running celery to send requests to Google Firebase in the background. It works fine when I use prefork. However if I switch to a threading alternative like gevent or eventlet, the tasks do not execute (even though they are received). It seems like celery is unable to connect to the network when I use gevent/eventlet.

```
    9-09-08 21:13:11,629: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: wallet.realtime.update_balance[783e2791-89ca-42eb-869e-64a04e8bff5b] pid:17399
    [2019-09-08 21:13:11,662: DEBUG/MainProcess] Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
    [2019-09-08 21:13:11,663: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting new HTTPS connection (2): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
    [2019-09-08 21:13:31,635: ERROR/MainProcess] Task wallet.realtime.update_balance[783e2791-89ca-42eb-869e-64a04e8bff5b] raised unexpected: ServiceUnavailable('Deadline Exceeded')

    google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded
```

It works perfectly fine with prefork, so shouldn't be a connectivity issue.

This is my celery config:

```
    celery --app=bosm2019 worker --pool=gevent --concurrency=100 -Ofair --loglevel=DEBUG
```

What should I do?